# Close modal after form have "saved"

Tags: javascript, splistitem, edit-form

Im trying to trigger a page reload after my editform is done.
I know that I can create a js function, "presaveitem". But this is called before the item is saved.

I need to trigger some custom JS after the item have been saved

Comment: See my answer there: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129852/how-can-i-call-a-custom-javascript-function-after-a-form-has-validated/129900#129900